# How to display text lot of times on HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html

i am new in web development , im working now with **Html** and **Php** and i wanna know if there is a way i can display a text on a different number of times due to a variable , i have a variable `$count` , so for example if `$count = 1` i want it to display the text one time like this :

```
<h1> This is a Text 1 </h1>
```

And if `$count = 3` i want it to be like this :

```
<h1> This is a Text 1 </h1>
<h1> This is a Text 2 </h1>
<h1> This is a Text 3 </h1>
```

I'll be so glad to have your help please

Comment: What have you done so far? Where is `$count`, in a `for`?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: i dont know yet what to try , wanna get some ideas @j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop , like this :

```
<?php
 for ($i = 0; $i <= count; $i++) {
     echo "<h1> This is a Text ".$i." </h1>";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
<?php
$count = 3;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
?>
<h1>This is a Text</h1>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a decent answer, but it is missing the count number inside the <h1> tags, echoing the `$i` variable inside the loop would get you all the way there.